# Having some issues with python bot

Tags: python, json, telegram, aiogram

So I was making a python bot, that sends results of it's work to Telegram.
it was working until yesterday. Now when im starting it it returns this error:

```
 File "E:\FindBot\handlers\users\start.py", line 4, in <module>
   from loader import dp
 File "E:\FindBot\loader.py", line 11, in <module>
   with open("include/sc_prices.json", encoding="utf-8") as file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'include/sc_prices.json'
```

Python verison 3.9
IDE Pycharm

Doubleckecked the path to file 100+ times, and if i want to insert absolute path to this file - start.py runs without any errors, but telegram bot itself isnt working, just returns "Process finished with exit code 0"

As i mentioned before, everything was fine until yesterday, nothing was changed in code, also reinstalled all libraries and reinstalled windows

Comment: Does ```include``` exist?   Does ```include/sc_prices.json``` exist?  It's better not to use a fixed ```include/sc_prices.json``` but use something less platform dependent as ```include/sc_prices.json``` is a Unix thing.  have you tried using ```os.path.join```?  "It was working until yesterday..."   What changed?

Comment: The code will look for `include/sc_prices.json` as a subfolder of **the current directory**, which is not necessarily the same directory where **your python script is**.  To see what the code is using as the current directory, you can use this `import os; print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: On a side note, why on earth would you **reinstall windows** to fix a simple missing file error??

Answer (score 0):

try using os.path to form path

check venv